Cannot create a User Account on iDRAC 9 with Redfish API
With the following code:
payload = {
        "UserName": new_user_name,
        "Password": new_user_password,
        "RoleId": "Administrator",
        "Enabled": True
    }

url = f"https://{idrac_ip}/redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts"
                    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                    response = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(admin_username, admin_password), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=False)

I am receiving the following error:
{
  "statusCode": 405,
  "body": "\"Failed to create user. Response: {\\\"error\\\":{\\\"@Message.ExtendedInfo\\\":[{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"Unable to run the method because the requested HTTP method is not allowed.\\\",\\\"MessageArgs\\\":[],\\\"MessageArgs@odata.count\\\":0,\\\"MessageId\\\":\\\"IDRAC.2.5.SYS402\\\",\\\"RelatedProperties\\\":[],\\\"RelatedProperties@odata.count\\\":0,\\\"Resolution\\\":\\\"Enter a valid HTTP method and retry the operation. For information about valid methods, see the Redfish Users Guide available on the support site.\\\",\\\"Severity\\\":\\\"Informational\\\"}],\\\"code\\\":\\\"Base.1.8.GeneralError\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"A general error has occurred. See ExtendedInfo for more information\\\"}}\""
}

I am able to return the allowed methods:
Allowed methods: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS

Not sure what I am missing here, I have made sure:

Redfish is enabled
I am using the 'root' account and it is set as an Administrator
Logs are showing that 'root' is accessing the iDRAC via Redfish
Password policy for new accounts is set to 0
I have also tried using a method that is to be deprecated in future releases with the same results: url = f"https://{idrac_ip}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/Accounts"
I have checked the provided schemas: https://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/

It is iDRAC 9 Firmware Version 5.10.30.00.

I don’t have an idrac but may be worth trying req.patch rather than req.post similar to this

Your post was exactly what I went through the last couple of days.  I was able to figure it out using Postman to try every possible way to see the objects.  To create a new user, try this path and use PATCH method (as Brian above mentioned):  https://{idrac}/redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts/x where x is any number from 1 to 16 (default administrator = 1) - this must be specified.  It's best to see what you already have in accounts first or the PATCH method would overwrite the existing account.  The payload should contain the below:
payload = {
"UserName": newuser,
"Password": newpassword,
"RoleId": "Administrator",
"Enabled": True
}

If you want to have more specific privilege (such as only allow "Login" or "Configure Users"), the path is https://{idrac}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/Attributes and the method is PATCH (again).  The payload would be (x is for Account ID)
payload = {
"Attributes":
{
    "Users.x.Privilege": 5
}
}

Just for grins, here are the specific numbers for the special privileges (e.g. Login (1) + Configure Users (4) = 5).

Login 1
Configure 2
Configure Users 4
Logs 8
System Control 16
Access Virtual Console 32
Access Virtual Media 64
System Operations 128
Debug 256

Hope this helps.
